# Using ngx-microsoft-bot-framework from Angular 10 application gives error No provider for ComService

Tags: angular, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created Azure Bot and trying to call it from my Angular web client. I have followed all the steps mentioned in this package guide at - [Bot Framework Library For Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-microsoft-bot-framework)

On implementing all the steps and running the application it gives me error -
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ComService -> ComService -> ComService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ComService!

[image: Com Error]

I have added the relevant Microsoft bot module in app module imports as well as in providers.
[image: App Module]

Is there anything I am missing?

Note: the demo site for this implementation is also not working - [Bot Demo Site](https://xtianus79.github.io/ngx-microsoft-bot-framework/)

Comment: Remove NgxMicrosoftBotFrameworkModule from providers array.

Comment: It gives same error with or without adding it in providers array

Comment: I was going to suggest opening an issue in the repo, but I see you've already done that! [Linking here](https://github.com/xtianus79/ngx-microsoft-bot-framework/issues/8) for consistency.

Comment: Couldn't find any solution to it so I ended up using following sample code for angular-
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/f.host-with-angular

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the necessary providers on your component declaration.

```
providers: [BotService, ComService, BotDirective, BotHelperDirective, StyleSetDirective]
```